# Laravel Eager Loading and dynamically bind model relationship

Tags: laravel-5, orm, model, eloquent

Laravel version: **5.3**

In my **User** model class i have a method like :

```
public function hasOneRelation($model)
{
    return $this->hasOne($model);
}
```

And then i call this method like below code:

```
User::hasOneRelation('App\Client')->first();
```

i got the correct value but is there any N+1 problem.....

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to eager load this dynamic relationship, so if you attempt to use this relationship in a loop, yes, you will end up with an N+1 problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any N+1 issue here because you won't be calling that as a property of a model. That and just stay away from calling that in a loop on your model.  You get the N+1 issue if you were to do something like:

```
//User Model
public function contract()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contract::class);
}

//Controller
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}

//View
<ul>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <li>{{$user->contract->type}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Loading the relation on each model within a loop instead of lazy loading it like:

```
//Controller
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('contract')->get();

    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you just face N+1 problem. Read laravel official doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).